# NameError: name 'random' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code:

```py
r = random.randint(1,10)
```

But for some reason it's giving me the error

> NameError: name 'random' is not defined

Other info: Mac, Python, 3.4.0 pylauncher

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You have to import the module [`random`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html):

```
import random

r = random.randint(1,10)
# ...
```

Answer (score 8):

```
>>> import random
>>> r = random.randint(1,10)
>>> r
10
```

Comment: Though this answer appears to be a duplicate of the accepted answer, it has the same time stamp as the accepted one. Hence, it should be upvoted as well.

Answer (score 2):

you need to import the random library with the `import` keyword

```
import random 
random.randint(1,10)    #no. between 0 and 10
```

Comment: while your answer is correct, please provide more information so OP understand your answer

Comment: Anything new from provided answers?